# How do I remove the Ubuntu customization kit from my install?

Tags: command-line, apt, execute-command

How do I remove the Ubuntu customization kit from my install? I no longer need it and have tried several ways get rid of it and don't know the command line command to get rid of it.

Comment: What is "Ubuntu customization kit"? Where did you get it?

Comment: The software name's `uck`. Why can't you uninstall it? If you installed it (as you should) from the official repositories, with APT, it should be as simple as `sudo apt remove uck`.

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`...

Either:

```
sudo apt-get purge uck
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -P uck
```